# Mesh is not visible in viewport or render

Tags: 3d-view, visibility

I am missing mesh from the viewport/ final render.

Tried recalculating normals as I have looked into the other questions before asking and that was not the issue, I have the eyeball and camera enabled as seen on my outliner.

The Faces are still there, but not visible as seen in the 2nd picture also the cycles settings are there too.

Also have hair particles on the mesh that is the only thing that is visible and that is the only modifier I have on that mesh

no physics enabled

If there is any other information that is needed please let me know and I will provide it

Thanks

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image: Emitter enabled]

[image: Vertex groups listed]

Comment: Does your object have any dupligroups? Is the particle system's *Emitter* option disabled, thus preventing the object from being renderable?

Comment: Added 2 new pictures that show. Yes the Emitter option is enabled and yes it has groups

Comment: I meant *Dupligroups*, not *Vertex Groups*, chech your *Object* tab under the properties window in the *Duplication* panel. Otherwise might be worth considering sharing an **as simplified as possible** [file showing the issue](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com)

Comment: I have it figured out. About to answer it

Comment: @Zak completely unrelated to your question, but I noticed that you have huge scale values on your hair emitter. If you want realistic grass dynamics, i would strongly recommend to aplly the scale on your emitter and to re-setup your hair system according to real-world scale.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Under the Maximum Draw Type it was set to "Wire"

To Fix this, Simply change it to "Solid" [image]